# when run git clone, get error: errno 10054

Tags: linux, windows, git, ssh, clone

When i use command git clone** to get the public code , it comes out these messages below:

```
unable to access 'https://github.com/jenkinsci/maven-snapshot-check-plugin.git/': OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection was reset, errno 10054
```

Anyone have some ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

the command below can solved the problem:

**git config --global http.sslVerify "false"**

Comment: This removes all security from your connection and makes it vulnerable to tampering.